# How to prevent form stripe validation

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I integrated stripe-element directly into a Woocommerce override (payment.php page) only, when submitting the form, if I check everything, but I don't fill in the credit card numbers, I don't have any error and he validates the order (on Stripe, I have a payment error).

If I only put 2 digits in the bank details, I have an error. But if it's empty, I don't have one.
I seek, I seek, but I cannot find. Can someone explain or is it please?

Thank you very much,

Here is the source code

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.

  card.on("change", function(result) {
    var displayError = document.querySelector("displayError");
    displayError.querySelector(".token").innerText = result.token.id;
    displayError.classList.add("submitted");
    result.complete("success");
  });

// // Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      document.cookie = "stripe_tkn=" + result.token.id;
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });

  
});

  

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  document.cookie = "stripe_tkn=" + result.token.id;
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
 }
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to ask, there's a large language barrier.

Comment: Sorry, I'm French and not very comfortable with this language.

Answer (score 0):

If the stripe element is empty, stripe applies a specific css code to the element.

You can use query.selector to test for this:

```
  const checkForCreditCardNumber = () => {
   if(document.querySelector('.StripeElement--empty')===null){return}
     let message = 'Please enter a credit card number'
     this.props.updateMessage(message)
     this.props.changeMessageColor('red')
  }
```